# When prototyping responsive web design, I have to consider how frontend dev. will do it: CSS Grid/Flexbox/Bootstrap?

Tags: interface, css, prototype

My question context:
I have to design a responsive website, that is now poorly responsive on bootstrap. I would like to start drawing IA of interface elements and how they act on several screen widths from desktop to mobile.

My frontend developers want to switch to CCS Grid or Flexbox. That's why they have asked me to check if there are any different rules when designing responsibility for Flexbox or CSS Grid.
I haven't found any info to answer their question, so maybe you guys have Idea if it affect my work, or not. If yes, how?

Comment: I would say “*no, not necessarily*”. The process I’m used to, is that the designer asks if he/she is unsure whether the idea or draft can be build with HTML/CSS. I then try to think of an implementation or - if necessary - build a prototype of that partial. In the end I can say yes in almost all cases. But the actual implantation is not interesting for the design process itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are behaviors native to **flexbox** that are very hard to achieve with just CSS floats and position elements. These include:

1. position of items in relation to one another (flex-direction, flex-wrap)
2. spacing of items between each other (e.g. justify-content: space-around)
3. ordering of items in html (no longer limited to document order)

So you have a lot more flexibility designing a responsive site with flexbox than without. This may influence your design. Here's a good primer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: THX,  i know that flex and css grid can do more than bootstrap, that is why we switch to new. However My question is. If, Before switching Do I have to consider it in my prototyping or it doesn't affect it. I, as a UX designer will draw how it moves - and flexible for repsonsibility

Comment: I find it is always useful to consider the technologies because it makes for an easier implementation. If you do know about flex and css grids you can design the interactions to be within their technical bounds - which makes it much easier for your developers to implement. So yes, if you can, consider it in your prototyping.